# Как наложить 2 картинки не используя контейнеров?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Надо в картинку `img` поместить в центр другую картинку (картинки являются первью видео, а вторая картинка это кнопка плей) только средствами css

Почему именно так? Потому что плагин, который я использую для грида фото умеет работать только с фото, а в новости может быть и другой медиаконтент

Возможно, найдется что-то лучше [Photoset Grid](http://stylehatch.github.io/photoset-grid/) которая сможет подобно скучивать фото выделяя одну или две в качестве основных (большего размера)

Comment: Через :before пробовал добавить картинку в и с помощью позиционирования поставить по центру?

Answer (score 1):

Внешний контейнер все равно должен быть:

```css
.item{
  position:relative;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.item__image{
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.item__play{
  position:absolute;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  border-radius:50px;
  border:5px solid #fff;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
  top:50%;
  margin:-25px auto 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition:box-shadow .3s ease;
}
.item__play:hover{
  box-shadow:0 0 0 transparent;
}
.item__play:active{
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img class="item__image" alt="Image" src='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg'/>
  <img class="item__play" alt="play" src='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg'/>
</div>
```

Если у вас html выглядит по-другому, то прикладывайте код к вопросу пожалуйста.

Comment: Проблема в том, что плагин пересобирает контейнер вытаскивая от туда все img, пример кода прям по ссылке что я оставлял в вопросе